# React Native not rerendering after state change

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, state

I realize that this is a common problem but I haven't found a solution that doesn't feel like it's just covering up the real problem. I have code in a component that is not being updated when the state changes. I'm pretty sure that the state is changing because when I save my code while the simulator is on the screen, it updates, but it doesn't updating when going to that screen normally. Also, in the code segment below there are two very similar functions. The first one works and renders properly. The second one works but doesn't rerender after updating.

```
fetchUsername().then((uname) => {
            setUsername(uname);
            return uname;
        }).then((uname) =>
            (fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID)
            .then((payments) => {
                return Promise.all(
                    payments.map(pid => {
                        return fetchPayment(pid)
                            .then(paymentDetails => {
                                return paymentDetails.sender === uname ? paymentDetails.value * paymentDetails.users.length : 0
                            })
                    })
                );
            }).then((paymentValues) => {
                const paymentSum = paymentValues.reduce((acc, val) => parseInt(acc) + parseInt(val), 0);
                setAmmountReceive(paymentSum);
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            }),
            fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID)
            .then((payments) => {
                return Promise.all(
                    payments.map(pid => {
                        return fetchPayment(pid)
                            .then(paymentDetails => {
                                return paymentDetails.users.includes(username) ? paymentDetails.value : 0
                            })
                    })
                );
            }).then((paymentValues) => {
                const paymentSum = paymentValues.reduce((acc, val) => parseInt(acc) + parseInt(val), 0);
                setAmmountOwe(paymentSum);
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            }))
```

Comment: If it is a component then `this.setState` should be called, can you also update the question with how the state is update and used in the render? is `setUsername(uname)` and rest of the similar methods are to update state or calling a method which internally updating the state?

Comment: Yes, setAmmountOwe(paymentSum), setAmmountReceive(paymentSum), setUsername(uname), are all used to set the state of the function. This code is not actually inside a component, I just call it that but I should be more specific. It's a function which I call in my screens to render the info generated by this code. It's still very strange to me how it's rendering the first part but not the second.